# Three Sum Algorithm can't find bug

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm trying to solve Three Sum (find all triplets that add to 0 within an array avoiding duplicate cases) but currently running into a bug I can't seem to find.

When the input is `[-1,0,1,2,-1,-4]`, it works fine.

With this input however, `[-1,0,1,2,-1,-4,-2,-3,3,0,4]` I'm getting this array as output:

`[[-1,-1,2],[-1,0,1],[-2,0,2],[-3,0,3],[-3,1,2],[-4,0,4],[-4,1,3]]`.

The correct output should be

`[[-4,0,4],[-4,1,3],[-3,-1,4],[-3,0,3],[-3,1,2],[-2,-1,3],[-2,0,2],[-1,-1,2],[-1,0,1]]`

So for some reasons my solution is omitting the triplets `[-3,-1,4]` and `[-2,-1,3]`.

```
var threeSum = function (nums) {
    const sorted = nums.sort()
    const output = []
    for (let i = 0; i < sorted.length - 2; i++)
        if (i === 0 || (i > 0 && sorted[i] !== sorted[i - 1])) {
            let lower = i + 1
            let higher = sorted.length - 1

            while (lower < higher) {
                const currentSum = sorted[i] + sorted[lower] + sorted[higher];
                if (currentSum === 0) {
                    output.push([sorted[i], sorted[lower], sorted[higher]])
                    while (sorted[lower] === sorted[lower + 1]) lower++
                    while (sorted[higher] === sorted[higher - 1]) higher--
                    lower++
                    higher--
                }

                else if (currentSum < 0) {
                    lower++
                } else {
                    higher--
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return output
 };
```

Comment: "Make it break." What do you mean by that? Is there stackoverflow, undefined read attempt, or something else? Please specify the error.

Comment: its missing a couple of the triplets in the output

Comment: Perhaps check input numbers are integers and less than 15 digits (or Javascript floating point accuracy could cause some results to be missed)

Comment: It's all small integers

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read up on [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). After doing some research and [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, try it yourself. If you're stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt and note exactly where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Your code avoids returning duplicate cases.  Are you sure these cases should be not counted?

Comment: Ok, I edited the question. It should be better and the issue more clear now.

Comment: Have to tried to debug your code and step line by line through your code. Follow the code flow, e.g. for `i == 1`. [How to debug small programs: StackOverflow is a question-and-answer site for specific questions about actual code; “I wrote some buggy code that I can’t fix” is not a question, it’s a story, and not even an interesting story.](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 2):

By default Javascript sorts via string comparison.

You want to sort numerically so use

```
nums.sort(function(a, b){return a - b});
```